# What does the "that" in "That's a bit young" refer to?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

Suppose the following conversation:

A: Your son really has a car? But he's only 10 years old. **That**'s a bit young, isn't it?

B: Oh, he's too young for a real car, but this isn't a real car.
It's only a toy.*

---

What does the "**That**" refer to? (Which part is it a pronoun for?)

1. 10 years old
2. your son

Comment: It would be very strange to refer to the son as "that" in this conversation, because we use *that* to refer to things that are distant, like "Do you see the man crossing the campus over there?  *That's* our security guard." but the son is not distant in this conversation.

Comment: @stangdon Depends on the context: in _That's my wife over there_, "that" does refer to a person. But in the OP it doesn't work in the same way.

Comment: @fev  Right, but in your example, the wife is distant, and the topic.  In the OP's sentence, the son is not the topic, distant or otherwise.

Comment: @stangdon Yes, exactly. In my example "that" is more emphatically deictic.

Comment: @stangdon: As fev says, ***that*** here refers to *[being] **10 years old***, not ***your son*** or ***he***. The usage might potentially be a bit confusing, but idiomatically it's so common I think learners have no choice but to take this usage on board.

Answer (score 4):

*That* refers to *10 years old*. You can read you sentence as:

> *That [age]* is a bit young.

or

> *That* (meaning *10 years old*) is a bit young.

Comment: Thank you so much, fev

Comment: You can say "he's a bit young", but that would be more of a personal comment about the boy; "that's a bit young" implies it is a bit young for anybody or in general.